# force:source:push GACK Error

Tags: salesforcedx

Per the instructions on the GACK page (https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) I am sharing my experience here.

When doing a `force:source:push -f` on our codebase, I get an error like so:

> UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 376972653-214226 (-3070748)

The json of the push itself reads like this:

```
"stack": "DeployFailed: Push failed.
at ALMError (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\core\\almError.js:44:19)
at MetadataRegistry.initializeMetadataTypeInfos.then.catch.e (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\lib\\source\\sourceApiCommand.js:57:31)
at tryCatcher (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:510:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:567:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:612:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\promise.js:687:18)
at Async._drainQueue (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:138:16)
at Async._drainQueues (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:148:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)\n    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)\nOuter stack:
at Function.wrap (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\@salesforce\\core\\lib\\sfdxError.js:151:27)
at SourcePushCommand.catch (C:\\Users\\jyoung\\AppData\\Local\\sfdx\\client\\7.2.0-179c9078fc\\node_modules\\salesforce-alm\\dist\\ToolbeltCommand.js:216:46)",
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Be aware that most of us here aren't employees of Salesforce, and so can't really help with GACKs. You should still raise a case with Salesforce Customer Support, if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks Derek - I don't have premium support, so they don't like me to create cases there either :) I'm just covering my bases... also, the GACK documentation seems to suggest they pay attention to this forum, but maybe that'st just wishful thinking.

Comment: Support will be responsive to gacks. A GACK is an issue on their internal server - its not (directly) something you can cause. Sometimes you can get lucky & another user will figure out a way to prevent the gack, and there are employees from salesforce on here, but only around 2 - and its unrealistic to expect them to answer every gack.  Given that its not code thats gacking, you'll probably need to contact support - we can't tell you to do anything differently, change your code, etc.

Comment: Excellent feedback - thank you! I will post it as per your suggestion.

Comment: You can also try posting to the [SFDX group on the Trailblazer Community](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HTp1) There and/or in your case, you'll want to also share your scratch org def, whether the code has pushed to a scratch org succesfully in the past, and what changes you've made since your last successful push to a scratch org. If you edit your question to include that information, you may be able to get some guidance from SFSE users that's not necessarily specific to the GACK, but to your sfdx setup generally.

Comment: Which I see you did. :-)